# Is there a way to make edit and continue work in lambda expressions?

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0, lambda

i've been searching google to see if there is a version of visual studio that supports edit and continue, or a plugin... didn't found anything.

Does anyone knows if edit and continue in lambda expressions is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible.

However, it is one of the highly requested features on VisualStudio's UserVoice. Consider voting for [Edit & Continue: Allow the modification of lambda's and anonymous methods](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4079440-edit-continue-allow-the-modification-of-lambda). A related feature [Debug Lambda expressions](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2049821-debug-lambda-expressions-planned) is being worked on. I think these features are related, but I'm not entirely sure.